# i need to know how can i invoke the alarm sound after the user sets the time

Tags: java

I have been trying for 2-3 days now to find a way to invoke the play() method which is my alarm sound with no real success...i have tried while and for loops, new TimerTasks with boolean flags with no success...the alarm sound is not triggered when it meets the user input so can i ask someone more experienced to tell me what i am doing wrong?

Here is my Commands class where the alarm sound is placed which itself is connected in the main class ClockGui

```
 package Clock;

 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat;
  import java.util.Calendar;
  import java.util.Timer;
 import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.*;
import sun.audio.*;

public class Commands {
ClockGui gui;
Time clock;
Timezones zone;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
int hour1 ;
int min1 ;
int sec1;

boolean alarmOn = false;


public Commands (ClockGui gui) {
     this.gui = gui;
     zone = new Timezones(gui);
     clock = new Time(gui);

}

public void setAlarm() {
      hour1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set the hour of the alarm \n in the form of '00' :"));
      min1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set the minutes of the alarm \n in the form of '00' :"));
      sec1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set the seconds of the alarm \n in the form of '00' :"));
      gui.alarm1.setText("" + df.format(hour1) + " : " + df.format(min1) + " : " + df.format(sec1));
      Timer timer2 = new Timer();
       TimerTask task2 = new TimerTask() {
           public void run(){
               Calendar timeNow = Calendar.getInstance();
               int hours = timeNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
               int mins = timeNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

               if (hours == hour1 && mins == min1) {
                   alarmOn = true;
               }

           }
       };
       timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(task2,0,1000);



 }

public void play() {
if(alarmOn == true){

    InputStream sound;
    try {
        sound = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\workspace\\Alarm Clock\\src\\Clock\\sound.wav"));
        AudioStream alarm = new AudioStream(sound);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(alarm);
    } catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

}

here is my main class

```
package Clock;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MenuEvent;
 import javax.swing.event.MenuListener;

 public class ClockGui implements ActionListener, MenuListener,   MouseListener {
  Time clock;
  Commands command;
  Timezones zone;
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Clock");
  JLabel label1 = new JLabel("The Time is now :");
  JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Stopwatch");
  JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Select a country :");
  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel5 = new JPanel();
  JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
  JButton start = new JButton("Start");
  JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
  Container contentPane = new Container();
  JTextField time = new JTextField(10);
  JTextField stopwatch = new JTextField(20);
  JTextField timeZone = new JTextField(6);
  JTextField alarm1 = new JTextField(7);
  JButton alarm = new JButton("Set Alarm");
  JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");


public ClockGui() throws IOException   {
    clock = new Time(this);
    command = new Commands(this);
    zone = new Timezones(this);
    makeFrame();
    if (command.alarmOn == true){
        command.play();
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException   {

    new ClockGui();



}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your problem is about the alarm not sounding while calling `play()` method or you don't know when to call the `play()` method?

Comment: my problem is that after setting boolean checks to meet the logic requirements the play() method is not actived/called even though as you can i have a boolean check that if alarmON is true the play() (alarm sound) should be called

Comment: When do you call `play()`? From your main method? Show us that code too.

Comment: some of the main class(the relevant stuff) i posted them above

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `alarmOn` variable and call `play()` instead of setting `alarmOn = true` in your TimerTask.

Comment: i did that and again nothing...i think the problem is that the user inputs arent assigned to the variable but i am not really sure thats why i am here